# Karma E2E Tests found but skipped and marked as fail

Tags: javascript, angularjs, web, karma-runner, angularjs-e2e

Given the e2e config:

```
module.exports = function(config) {
    config.set({
        basePath: '../',

        files: [
            'E2E/**/*.js'
        ],

        autoWatch: false,

        browsers: ['Chrome'],

        frameworks: ['ng-scenario'],

        singleRun: true,

        proxies: {
            '/': 'http://localhost:8000/'
        },

        plugins: [
            'karma-junit-reporter',
            'karma-chrome-launcher',
            'karma-jasmine',
            'karma-ng-scenario'
        ],

        junitReporter: {
            outputFile: 'test_out/e2e.xml',
            suite: 'e2e'
        },

        urlRoot: '/_karma_/'
    });
};
```

and the scenario:

```
'use strict';

/* http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/dev_guide.e2e-testing */

describe('Mailing App', function () {

    it('should filter the phone list as user types into the search box', function () {
        expect(true).toBe(true);
    });

    it('should filter the phone list as user types into the search box', function () {
        expect(Element('foo').count()).toEqual(1);
    });

    describe('Sample Test', function () {

        beforeEach(function () {
            browser().navigateTo('../../Client/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml');
        });

        it('should filter the phone list as user types into the search box', function () {
            pause();
            expect(Element('.ng-binding')).toBeDefined();
        });
    });
});
```

The programs finds the 3 tests but does not pass or fail them, rather skips them.
Running the script (with windows 8.1, git bash)  returns says:

> Karma v0.12.1 server started atHTTP://localhost:9876/*karma*/"
>
> starting Chrome Connected on Socket Chrome 31.0.1650 Executed 0 of 3
>
> (skipped 3) Error

Any idea why tests that don't even need to traverse the site or look at the DOM etc can be found but can not be run?

Answer (score 1):

Ok, not sure if this will help anyone but basically the issue was I didn't realise that angular-scenario.js is not part of the Karma test running suite, it is from before karma when tests were running with testacular.

angular-scenario.js was being included as part of the file includes with the **/*.js wildcards.

Once I changed it to no longer see that it seems to now be working, guess I would have expect some kind of conflicting functions or stuff not defined to be thrown, if classes were messing each other up.